# Jetty 12 ResourceHandler configuration and MIME-types issues

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-12

I'm migrating to jetty 12, and I'm encountering some issues with the ResourceHandler. I'm using three, one for /robots.txt, one for /sitemap.xml and one for all other files at /files/.

I'm having two issues:

- /robots.txt and /sitemap.xml doesn't work. It gives a 301 and rewrites the url with appended slash (/robots.txt/) and then gives a 404.
- /files/ does send the correct files, but never sends any Content-Type headers no matter the MimeTypes I supplied

I noticed the ResourceHandler now needs to have a ContextHandler wrapped, or else I get a nullPointerException immediately. I also couldn't get ResourceHandler#setBaseResourceAsString to work at all, but it seems to work with /files/ when using ContextHandler#setBaseResourceAsString.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    //...

    // Configure jetty
    jettyServer = new Server();

    //...

    // Calls all added handlers in list order
    Handler.Sequence root = new Handler.Sequence();
    jettyServer.setHandler(root);

    root.addHandler(new GreeterHandler(this));

    // Create a PathMappingsHandler to hold mappings
    PathMappingsHandler mapHandler = new PathMappingsHandler();
    root.addHandler(mapHandler);

    // Add handlers to ContextHandlerCollection
    // First, all dynamic handlers for user facing pages
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from(pageDescriptions.get(PAGE_INDEX).url()), new IndexHandler(this));
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from(pageDescriptions.get(PAGE_LOGIN).url()), new LoginHandler(this));
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from(pageDescriptions.get(PAGE_LOGOUT).url()), new LogoutHandler(this));
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from(pageDescriptions.get(PAGE_REGISTER).url()), new RegisterHandler(this);

    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/robots.txt"), singleFileHandler("/robots.txt", "resources/private/robots.txt"));
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/sitemap.xml"), singleFileHandler("/sitemap.xml", "resources/private/sitemap.xml"));

    // the rest of the /public folder
    ResourceHandler publicFilesHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    publicFilesHandler.setServer(jettyServer);
    publicFilesHandler.setDirAllowed(true);
    //publicFilesHandler.setUseFileMapping(true);

    MimeTypes.Mutable types = new MimeTypes.Mutable();
    types.addMimeMapping("js", "text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
    types.addMimeMapping("css", "text/css; charset=utf-8");
    types.addMimeMapping("svg", "image/svg+xml");

    publicFilesHandler.setMimeTypes(types);

    ContextHandler h = new ContextHandler(publicFilesHandler, "/files");
    h.setBaseResourceAsString("resources/public/");
    mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/files/*"), h);

    jettyServer.setRequestLog(new CustomRequestLog(new Slf4jRequestLogWriter(), CustomRequestLog.NCSA_FORMAT + " - %D"));

    //logger.info(root.dump());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a ResourceHandler that serves a single file.
 */
private Handler singleFileHandler(String contextPath, String filePath) {
    ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
    handler.setServer(jettyServer);

    ContextHandler result = new ContextHandler(handler);
    result.setBaseResourceAsString(filePath);

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: I also tried the following simplest setup from the docs, but I couldn't get it do produce anything other than 404s:

```
ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();   
Resource r = ResourceFactory.of(rh).newResource("resources/public/");
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(r)) {
     throw new IOException("Resource is not a readable directory");
}
rh.setBaseResource(r);
rh.setDirAllowed(true);
rh.setUseFileMapping(true);
rh.setServer(jettyServer);
mapHandler.addMapping(PathSpec.from("/files2/*"), rh);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ResourceHandler` has a `Resource` as its base.

That base `Resource` has to exist, must be a directory, and must be readable by the `ResourceHandler`.

When you call `ResourceFactory.newResource("resources/public/")` that call can result in a null if the resource isn't found.

The string `"resources/public/"` is an incomplete path that is subject to all kinds of relative path behaviors.

Double check that the result of `newResource(String)` is a `Resource` and not null.

If it is null, use a `Path` object and `newResource(Path)` instead.

Here's some examples to work from.

**Using a `Path` object**

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resources;

ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();   
Path baseDir = Path.of("resources/public/");
if (!Files.isDirectory(baseDir))
    throw new IOException("Path is not a directory: " + baseDir);
if (!Files.isReadable(baseDir))
    throw new IOException("Path is not readable: " + baseDir);
Resource base = ResourceFactory.of(rh).newResource(baseDir);
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(base))
    throw new IOException("Resource is not a readable directory"); + 
rh.setBaseResource(base);
// ...
```

**Using `Resource` object**

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resources;

ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();   
Resource base = ResourceFactory.of(rh).newResource("resources/public/");
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(base))
    throw new IOException("Resource is not a readable directory"); + 
rh.setBaseResource(base);
// ...
```

**Using `URI` object**

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resources;

ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();   
URI uri = getURIToBase(); // must be an absolute URI
Resource base = ResourceFactory.of(rh).newResource(uri);
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(base))
    throw new IOException("Resource is not a readable directory"); + 
rh.setBaseResource(base);
// ...
```

**Referencing a ClassLoader loader resource**

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resources;

ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();   
boolean searchSystemClassLoader = true;
Resource base = ResourceFactory.of(rh)
    .newClassLoaderResource("resources/public/", searchSystemClassLoader);
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(base))
    throw new IOException("Resource is not a readable directory"); + 
rh.setBaseResource(base);
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

The simplest example from the manual still just produces 404s, and resources/public/ is a valid reachable path. I've posted the code in the original post.

Comment: I've added some example code that you should use if you want to use relative paths like that.

Comment: Thank you for the great examples. I've confirmed the Resource is valid and points to the correct location in the filesystem, both with the debugger and with your suggested changes. ResourceHandler still misbehaves, giving a 404 on any request.

Comment: For some reason, the mime-type issues have now resolved with the /files/-endpoint, but I still can't make it serve the single files /robots.txt and /sitemap.xml.
Also, /files2/ still doesn't do anything but 404, even with a valid Resource. I've tried using a Path as well, to no avail.